# Loop through array of gmarker objects and only keep unique locations?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-markers, javascript-objects

I currently have an array of gmarker objects and there are duplicate gmarkers for the same location (latitude and longitude) but with different info windows. This is fine but I want to use marker clusters and only represent these locations once.

Is there a way to loop through the array and perhaps create another array which only contains then unique locations? (latitude, longitude)

I was trying something like this:

```
            var size = 0;
            var uniqueCustomers = []
            for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
                if (uniqueCustomers.indexOf(gmarkers[i]) < 0) {
                    uniqueCustomers[size] = gmarkers[i];
                    size = size + 1;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple way to do it, but one of them is just creating a "key" based on the latlng of each marker, check in your new object (not array) uniqueCustomers if the key is already set, and if not add the marker to uniqueCustomers.

```js
var gmarkers = [] ;

var coords = [
  {lat : 42.1, lng:3.4},
  {lat : 42.2, lng:3.4},
  {lat : 42.3, lng:3.4},
  {lat : 42.4, lng:3.4},
  {lat : 42.1, lng:3.4},
  {lat : 42.2, lng:3.4}
] ;

for ( var i in coords )
{
  gmarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
       position:coords[i]
  })) ;
}

var size = 0;
var uniqueCustomers = {} ;

// Loop on the 6 markers
for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
  // Create a key to identify tje position of the marker
  var key = gmarkers[i].position.lat() + ',' + gmarkers[i].position.lng() ;
  
  // If this key is not already on uniqueCustomers, then we add the marker with this key to uniqueCustomers, so at the next loops if it exists we don't add it another time
  if ( typeof uniqueCustomers[key] == 'undefined' )
    uniqueCustomers[key] = gmarkers[i] ;
}

console.log('gmarkers.length',gmarkers.length) ; // 6
console.log('uniqueCustomers.length',Object.keys(uniqueCustomers).length) ; // 4
console.log('uniqueCustomers',Object.keys(uniqueCustomers)) ; // Display only uniques
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Comment: You're welcome ;) please consider to check this answer as good so people having the same problem could easily see this is the answer.